# What are different ways to use enum in Java?

Tags: java, enums

Let say, I have below enum class in java, How would I use to access it in different ways?

```
public enum DayOfWeek {
    SUNDAY(0),
    MONDAY(1),
    TUESDAY(2),
    WEDNESDAY(3),
    THURSDAY(4),
    FRIDAY(5),
    SATURDAY(6);

    Integer label;

    DayOfWeek(Integer label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public Integer getValue() {
        return label;
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean, "access it in different ways" ?

Comment: If today is Saturday or Sunday then return false.

'LocalDateTime today = LocalDateTime.now();

 if(today.getDayOfWeek().name().equals(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY.toString()) || today.getDayOfWeek().name().equals(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY.toString())){
                        return false;
                    }'

Comment: @Ajay if you need to add extensive amounts of code please add them to your question (using the [edit] function), not in comments. (preferably with an explanation about *why* you're adding that code)

Comment: Accidentally, in this particular case you don't need to assign those values yourself, as you can rely on the `ordinal()` Enum method, that returns precisely those values for your constants.

Answer (score 2):

Returns the Object of type Enum:

```
DayOfWeek myType = DayOfWeek.MONDAY;
```

Returns the label of type Integer:

```
Integer myInt = DayOfWeek.TUESDAY.getValue(); // 1
```

Returns the Enum constant of the specified Enum type with the specified name:

```
DayOfWeek myType = DayOfWeek.valueOf("THURSDAY");
```

> Throws **IllegalArgumentException** if the specified enum type has no constant with the specified name OR **NullPointerException** if specified class object does not represent an enum type (e.g. null)

Returns the default string representation of the Enum Object:

```
String myEnumName = DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY.toString(); // "WEDNESDAY"
```

Returns all Enum types as an Array:

```
DayOfWeek[] values = DayOfWeek.values();
```